# yq - Print a string conditionally

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to generate a file `CHANGELOG.md` from a YAML file with [`mikefarah/yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

From the following YAML file:

```
releases:
  - name: v0.0.2
    changes:
      added:
        - Second feature (#3)
  - name: v0.0.1
    changes:
  - name: v0.0.0
    changes:
      added:
        - Bootstrap the project (#1)
        - First feature (#2)
```

I would like to generate the following:

```
## v0.0.2
### Added
- Second feature (#3)

## v0.0.1

## v0.0.0
### Added
- Bootstrap the project (#1)
- First feature (#2)
```

I got a close result with the following recipe:

```
.releases[] as $release | (
  "## " + $release.name,
  "### Added",
  "- " + $release.changes.added[],
  ""
)
```

However there is an extra `### Added` below `## v1.0.1`:

```
## v0.0.2
### Added
- Second feature (#3)

## v0.0.1
### Added

## v0.0.0
### Added
- Bootstrap the project (#1)
- First feature (#2)
```

I've tried to make the `### Added` conditional by using `select` and `with` but didn't succeed (cf. [Logic without if/elif/else](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#logic-without-if-elif-else)).
Is there a way to conditionally print the string `### Added`?

Comment: Your input and output don't match up (`v0` vs `v1`, `Second feature` vs `Add the exit code segment`, etc.)

Comment: @pmf, thanks for noticing it. I've updated the question to make it coherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first building the result array, and just then iterate over it:

```bash
.releases[] as $release | (
  "## " + $release.name, (
    $release.changes.added | (
      select(.) | ["### Added"]
    ) + map("- " + .) | .[]
  ),
  ""
)
```

```
## v0.0.2
### Added
- Second feature (#3)

## v0.0.1

## v0.0.0
### Added
- Bootstrap the project (#1)
- First feature (#2)
```